# Why PHP allows violation of LSP in exceptions but not in regular classes (Declaration of.. should be compatible..)?

Tags: php

Ok, check this out:

```
class MyParent
{
    public function myF($one, $two, $three)
    {
    }
}


class MyChild extends MyParent
{
    public function myF($one)
    {
    }
}
```

This throws the `Strict standards: Declaration of MyChild::myF() should be compatible with MyParent::myF()` - this is due to no *overloading* support in a weak-typed language, but the nice side effect is that it enforce LSP. **No problem with that**.

What puzzles me is that the following code doesn't throw the same error, even if [\Exception's own __construct() takes three argument](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php):

```
class MyChild extends \Exception
{
    public function __construct($first)
    {
    }
}
```

Why is that? why is the behavior for exception different? is this offically documented on the php.net site?

Comment: Constructors are different than other functions. Try adding a constructor to your `MyParent` class and add a different constructor to `MyChild`. It will work fine. What i mean to say is: It's not different for the exception class vs orther classes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413829/why-does-php-allow-incompatible-constructors

Comment: @MeneerVenus : That was it, thanks!

Comment: @georg Now that Meneer pointed out the real issue, I flagged my own question as duplicate of the one you reported. That's it, thanks!